# Layout being rendered twice

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework-mvc, zend-controller

I seem to have a problem with my layout displaying twice. I was wondering if this was caused by something in my front controller plugin (see below) which utilises Zend Layout only for a particular module and not in the main application. Any answers will be much appreciated. Thanks

```
class My_Controller_Plugin_AdoptLayout extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
```

{

```
    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {

            $moduleName = $request->getModuleName();                

            if ($moduleName == 'some-module') {

                    if (!Zend_Layout::isEnabled()) {

                            $view = new Zend_View(array('encoding' => 'UTF-8'));
                            $view->addScriptPath(ROOT_DIR . '/modules/some-module/views/scripts/');
                        $view->doctype('XHTML1_STRICT');

                            $viewRenderer = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer($view);
                        Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($viewRenderer);  

                            Zend_Layout::startMvc();
                            $layout = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance();
                            $layout->setLayout('default');
                            $layout->setLayoutPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/some-module/views/scripts/layouts/');
                            $layout->setView($view);                        
                    }

            }                                                           
    }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

This is typically caused by the ErrorController in my experience. I usually clear the response to make sure there's no nesting:

```
public function errorAction() {

        $this->getResponse()->clearBody();

//handle error ........

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this problem when using _forward or when I redirected to the errorController within a preDispatch plugin. You could check for these things.

Also i'm a little suspicious about the line:

```
$layout->setView($view);
```

Is it necessary. Doesn't Zend automatically assign the view to the layout.

Comment: Thanks andho. I wondered if it may be _forward actually but I really need to use it as I have to pass form values between actions and can't seem to get it to work with $this->_helper->redirector.

I had to create a new view object because the main application uses a Zend_View/Smarty hybrid and I don't want to change all my templates as they are pure Zend_View.

Comment: Why would you need to pass form data to another action? Is the action in the same Controller. If so can't you call $this->otherAction(); Or use action chaining but this might potentially render another view unless you switch off rendering for either one of the actions

Answer (score 0):

If you call an action from an Ajax call and your layout gets called twice, you could set

```
$this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
```

in the Action.

At my project I also made a wrong ajax call, which made it render another time. Hope this helps